# Determining whether the following is injective, surjective, bijective, or neither.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Although this problem is like one the questions posted here, it's not quite the same. I believe all I really needed to understand was the way to think about this in a way that made sense. This does not involve cubing something, but has similar properties to the ones I viewed already.

I'm rather confused on how to determine whether the following function is injective, surjective, bijective, or neither--

---

Given: $f : \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $f(x) = 2x$

---

Since the domain and codomain of this function are only concerned with the natural numbers (1 through infinity), but when it comes to showing how they are one-to-one and onto I confuse myself.

I already know that given the information I currently have that a function is injective when $f(x) = f(y)$ . In other words, for each value in the domain it, at most, maps to the codomain only once for each value.

I also know that a function is surjective (onto) when $f(x) = y$. How do I apply this concept in this problem I'm working through?

Comment: Hint: Does there exist any element in the domain such that $f(x) = 3$? For injectivity, try proving that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \rightarrow x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: You may find [some of these similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=determine+surjective+injective) helpful.

Comment: That helps me a lot to understand it I think a little more. So I'm looking for a specific counterexample to prove that it's not injective or surjective in other words, right? Correct me if I'm wrong @Hyperion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine whether a function is injective, surjective, or bijective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531656/determine-whether-a-function-is-injective-surjective-or-bijective)

Comment: Already checked it @Brian, I do not believe it's the same question just similarly formatted, but that could help me further now that I know the correct definitions.

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is pretty garbled. Each value in the domain maps to a single value in the codomain. That's the definition of a function and has nothing to do with injective or surjective.

I suggest you think about those two concepts with words rather than $f$ and $x$ and $y$.

*Injective* means you never map to something in the codomain more than once (but you don't have to get to them all).

*Surjective* means that you can map to everything in the codomain (but may get to some of them multiple times).

*Bijective* means injective and surjective.

Now think  about the function from the natural numbers to the natural numbers that doubles its input, and check those properties.

Comment: Thank you, Ethan. Those definitions help me a lot more